# HTML Images extend farther and block links

Tags: html, css, image, hyperlink, header

Images I place are blocking me from clicking links, and I think it is because the image is possibly larger than I thought (though I think I cropped it and I am not sure if it is something else.

Here is a picture (I moved he image as far over as I could in order to avoid this issue, but I would like to move the image closer if this problem can be fixed and I feel it will be helpful to know in the future):

[image: Picture of header]

Note: If I move it right it does not push the content or anything, it just makes the links in the nav bar unclickable (if that was not clear).

Here is the HTML:

```
                    <nav>
                    <ul>
                        <li class="current"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="jehovah'sWitness.html">Jehovah's Witness</a></li>
                        <li><a href="blockPrinting.html">Wood Block Print</a></li>
                        <li><a href="jazz.html">Jazz</a></li>
                        <li><a href="abercrombie.html">Being Ethical and Socially Responsible</a>    </li>
                    </ul>
                    </nav>

                <div class="container">

                <header>
                    <h1>
                        <img src="images/banner.png" alt="banner">
                        <a href="index.html">Designer Websites</a>
                    </h1>
                </header>
```

and my CSS:

```
            nav ul
                {
                list-style-type: none;
                text-align: center;
                }
            nav ul li
                {    
                padding: 5px;
                display: inline-block;
                border: solid 1px black;
                color: black;
                background-color: tan;
                }

            .current
                {
                    background-color: yellow;
                }

            body
                {
                background-color: tan;
                font-family: Arial, "Times New Roman", "Sans Serif", Georgia;
                }

            .container
                {
                width: 80%;
                max-width: 960px;
                margin:0px auto;
                }

            h1 img
                {
                height: 40%;
                position:absolute;
                left:-15px;
                top: -30px;
            }
```

New picture with the absolute position removed:

[image: New Picture]

Comment: Trying something like this http://codepen.io/MizR/pen/yyYOpX ?

Comment: @MizanurRahman Yes, that is how I would like it to look, but I am not quite sure how that is done. The HTML is the same (minus the obvious fact you put in a different image) and for the CSS I see you remove the img information I had. I am not quite understanding (and by quite I mean at all) how this is working.

Comment: explained in answer. :)

Answer (score 2):

I think your "absolute" positioned banner image was floating over navbar. That's the reason it was not clickable.

Remove this code (You may keep the "height" to set fixed height for your image)

```
h1 img {
    height: 40%;
    position: absolute;
    left: -15px;
    top: -30px;
}
```

Now image and heading will be left aligned. You can simply align them by adding text-align:center in .container. Or you can add this code:

```
header {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: I now have: "header
 {
 text-align: center;
 }

h1 img
 {
 height: 40%;
 width: 40%;
 }" but with that my banner is on the right (I had to change the width because it was too large otherwise. I will add a new picture to show you how it looks.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're facing now. Because it's working fine here http://codepen.io/MizR/pen/yyYOpX . If banner is too large, Just simply resize the image. Or reduce the %.:)

Comment: I tried resizing the image (the actual file) and then putting it there but it does not seem to work. This is pretty weird considering how the natural flow would have it be on the left, so I really have no clue what is happening. I appreciate the help though it is not quite working as it should.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this in order to put anchor "above" the img

```
h1 img {
    z-index: 1;
}
h1 a {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

Comment: I tried doing that but it did not seem to work. If I move the image over it still blocks out the links I can click on (though I noticed it is only for links to the right of the image).